# Json config to mongo query conversion

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write a function that converts a json config into an aggregation pipeline.

The function should take as inputs the json config and also the collection name on which to perform the query.

The json config is as follows :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("64906cc108eb0f4f7986626e"),
"name" : "name",
"calculations" : [
    {
        "numerator" : {
            "filters" : [
                {
                    "attribute" : "Column1",
                    "operator" : "$eq",
                    "value" : ["value"]
                },
                {
                    "attribute" : "Column2",
                    "operator" : "$nin",
                    "value" : [
                        "AAA",
                        "BBB"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute" : "Column3",
                    "operator" : "$lt",
                    "value" : NumberInt(25)
                }
            ],
            "group_by" : [
                "Column1"
            ],
            "aggregation_method" : "SUM",
            "aggregation_column" : "Column3"
        },
        "denominator" : {
            "filters" : [

            ],
            "group_by_numerator" : false,
            "aggregation_method" : "MAX",
            "aggregation_column" : "Column4"
        }
    }
],
"threshold_min" : -0.15,
"threshold_max" : null,
"edit_date" : "2023-06-19",
"status" : "ACTIVE",
"version" : NumberInt(1)}
```

The idea is as follows :
There are mainly two parts to the calculation, first a numerator, which contains multiple filters that are formatted in a fashion to simplify the conversion, followed by a group by on the filtered data with the corresponding aggregation.

The denominator follows the same logic, if no filter is specified and group_by_numerator is set to false, then the aggregation method is applied to the whole range of the aggregation column, otherwise the groupby would be the same as the numerator.

After that we need to divide the numerator by the denominator, and check that the value lies within the thresholds.

To do so I have written the following function :

```
def apply_quality_check(config, collection_name):

# Create pipeline stages based on the config
pipeline = []

# Numerator stage
numerator_filters = config['calculations'][0]['numerator']['filters']
numerator_groupby = config['calculations'][0]['numerator']['group_by']
numerator_aggregation_method = config['calculations'][0]['numerator']['aggregation_method']
numerator_aggregation_column = config['calculations'][0]['numerator']['aggregation_column']


numerator_stages = []
for filter_ in numerator_filters:
    operator = filter_['operator']
    attribute = filter_['attribute']
    value = filter_['value'][0]
    
    stage = {
        '$match': {f'${attribute}': {operator: value}}
    }
    numerator_stages.append(stage)

pipeline.append(numerator_stages)


numerator_groupby_stage = {
    '$group': {
        '_id': {f'${column}': f'${column}' for column in numerator_groupby},
        'numerator_value': {f'${numerator_aggregation_method}': f'${numerator_aggregation_column}'}
    }
}
pipeline.append(numerator_groupby_stage)

# Denominator stage
denominator_filters = config['calculations'][0]['denominator']['filters']
denominator_groupby_numerator = config['calculations'][0]['denominator']['group_by_numerator']
denominator_aggregation_method = config['calculations'][0]['denominator']['aggregation_method']
denominator_aggregation_column = config['calculations'][0]['denominator']['aggregation_column']

denominator_stages = []
for filter_ in denominator_filters:
    operator = filter_['operator']
    attribute = filter_['attribute']
    value = filter_['value'][0]
    
    stage = {
        '$match': {f'${attribute}': {operator: value}}
    }
    denominator_stages.append(stage)

pipeline.append(denominator_stages)

if denominator_groupby_numerator:
    denominator_groupby_stage = {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {f'${column}': f'${column}' for column in numerator_groupby},
            'denominator_value': {f'${denominator_aggregation_method}': f'${denominator_aggregation_column}'}
        }
    }
else:
    denominator_groupby_stage = {
        '$group': {
            '_id': None,
            'denominator_value': {f'${numerator_aggregation_method}': f'${denominator_aggregation_column}'}
        }
    }
pipeline.append(denominator_groupby_stage)

# Compute the result
pipeline.append({
    '$project': {
        '_id': 0,
        'result': {'$divide': ['$numerator_value', '$denominator_value']}
    }
})

# Apply threshold check
threshold_min = config['threshold_min']
threshold_max = config['threshold_max']
pipeline.append({
    '$match': {'result': {'$gte': threshold_min, '$lte': threshold_max}}
})

# Execute pipeline
result = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))
return result
```

But I get an error : Expected 'pipeline' to be BSON docs (or equivalent), but got primitive.A instead

Any advice on how to fix this issue, and does executing such an aggregation pipeline in a single time good practice ?